# Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Permission denied

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Description:

The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception detail:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: permission denied
```

Comment: paste code snippets where you getting this error.

Comment: A little more context would be nice. Perhaps you can share some code. Preferably the code that initiates this exception.

Comment: here is the error

Comment: Security Exception 
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Permission denied

Comment: Source Error: 

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have used Third party dll.

The exception itself states that change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Have a look at ASP.NET Trust Levels and Policy Files and How to resolve Security Exception. This exception can be due to lack of proper trust level in the machine.config file on the server.You can contact the administrator for further assistance.
For e.g :

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```